# Custom color on underline text when email is sent from Outlook to gmail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, gmail, html, css

Is there a way to keep the color on the underlined text when an email is sent from Outlook to gmail?

Links gets a blue/purple underline, and all other underlines are set to black.

I really need to have control of the color of the underlines when sending from Outlook.

Comment: Does it stay when you send from outlook to outlook? What about from gmail to gmail? What about gmail imap in outlook? I'm not convinced it's an outlook problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use inline styling? I know gmail and outlook can be finicky when it comes to external styling sheets. 
use html :

```
<u style="color: #FFFFFF;">Your Text Goes Here</u>
```

Use hex colors or words to change the color: (#FFFFFF) (Black)

I realize this may be a late answer but it might come useful to someone else :)